# Alternative to Thead.Sleep? in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have another thread polling user input. This thread is the main thread and can sleep minutes at a time. If the user hits wants to quit it may be 2+ minutes before the console window shuts down which may feel not responsive.

How can i make this thread wake up from Thread.Sleep? Do i need to use another function to sleep and pass in a bool ref for it to check when the thread wake up and end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **Monitor.Wait instead, and call Monitor.Pulse or Monitor.PulseAll**
to wake the thread up.

Comment: Don't forget to mention you need to use this inside a `lock` statement or a Monitor.Enter/Exit pair.

Comment: I would have not figure this out without that lock comment

Answer (score 4):

The solution is "Don't sleep on your UI thread". You should have a thread waiting for user input (not polling), and if you have a thread which needs to sleep (which probably isn't the case - it sounds like a hackish workaround to a different problem), then that should be separate thread that isn't handling the interface.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the blocking queue:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163427.aspx#S4

Answer (score 0):

Couple of suggestions:

1. If your using explicit threads you can try setting ThreadType to "Background" to prevent it from blocking an exit.
2. Try this as how you block:

main thread:

```
AutoResetEvent waitingEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
bool doneFlag = false
Thread myUIInputThread = new Thread(someFunction);

myUIInputThread.Start(waitingEvent);

while (!doneFlag) {
   doneFlag = waitingEvent.WaitOne(1000);
   if (!doneFlag) {
      Console.Writeline("Still waiting for the input thread...");
   }
}
```

In some function:

```
public void someFunction(object state) {
   Console.Write ("Enter something: ");
   Console.Readline();
   //... do your work ....

   ((AutoResetEvent)state).Set();
}
```

- Not tested for exactness... YMMV :)